# Marketing Cloud - retrieve message name from SMSMessageTracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, sms, sendsmsactivity

I want to retrieve sms message name & campaign name from SMSMessageTracking data view. How to do that? Because i need message name & campaign name to calculate my sms campaign performance.

I know i can get message name & campaign name from standart report "SMS Message Detail Report", but that report still unstable for scheduling (sometimes my schedule report is missing) maybe because we send huge amount sms everyday

Sorry for my bad english, i hope you understand my question.
Cheers..

Comment: You have the CampaignID in the SMSMessageTracking dv, why not use that?

Comment: i forget to mention. In my SMSMessageTracking report result, CampaignID have null record. I don't know why